# Modifying the message in flash.message

Tags: validation, grails

I have a method where I do some validation and it returns the error code, depending on the kind of error it is. So in the controller, when I do the validation and it returns the error code desired, I want to display the error message specific to that code. But all the messages are always "info like", the blue kind of flash message. What if I want the red one, error-like flash message? I've been looking into documentation for a while and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to accomplish this I usually do something like:

```
flash.message = "you screwed up"
flash.error = true
redirect action: "foo"
```

Then in the GSP

```
<g:if test="${flash.error && flash.message}">
   <div class="error">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put whatever you want into the `flash` scope, so what I tend to do is put "info like" messages into `flash.message` and "error like" messages into `flash.error`. Then in my view I test for each:

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}"><div class="message">${flash.message}</div></g:if>
<g:if test="${flash.error}"><div class="error">${flash.error}</div></g:if>
```